# does sisoDB use sql server database to store data

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, nosql, document-database, sisodb

I'm looking for a NoSQL database to use with asp.net , and I came to [sisoDB](http://www.sisodb.com/) . but as I understood it uses Sql server to save data and so it can use sql server features like security and ... .

is it correct ? and what are pros and cons of this approach ?

Comment: http://www.code972.com/blog/2011/05/sisodb-the-wrong-solution-to-the-wrong-problems/

Comment: @David: And that post is old but if we should go that route:  http://daniel.wertheim.se/2012/03/11/ranting-is-good-for-you/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of now the storage is using SQL Server 2008, 2012 - Express edition and above as well as SQLCE, but not in a traditional manner: http://sisodb.com/wiki/core-concepts

I'm planning on other providers as well and also to bring full-text search plugins.

Comment: I really like it , specially this idea " I relatively quickly discovered that I missed all the great infrastructure that SQL-server provides. Security, replication, scheduler etc " . one of things that I was really worry about is NoSQL databases security . but using this approach I can rely on Sql Server mature security system while using a document database style ... good job Daniel

Comment: Yeah, but remember, As with all data access technologies,there of course are shortcomings. Scaling, if needed, is probably easier with some NoSQL techs designed for it from the beginning But which ever tech you go with; evaluate per case and context. Don't try to find "the single tool".

Comment: That is what I've done , SisoDB was my last finding , I started by RavenDB , then MongoDB , ChouchDB ... but none of them fulfill this specific project requirements and just when I was almost Disappointed to find a nosql solution and was planning to back to sql server , I found sisoDB . thank you